# After reducing an SQL date down to MMM-yyyy using format how can I then order by Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, format

I am trying to group some aggregate numbers into months. The values stored are full datetime. I have successfully done this using the below statements but I can no longer order by date (instead it uses August as the first in the list as it begins with A).
My question is how can I now make the field RevDate either a Date field, or at least order correctly the months?

```
 SELECT
   tbl1.AName
  , tbl1.AStore
  , tbl1.AVr
  ,Count ( tbl2.RevTag1) as Tag1
  ,Count ( tbl2.RevTag2) as Tag2
  ,Count ( tbl2.RevTag3) as Tag3
  ,FORMAT ( tbl2.RevDateTime,'MMM-yyyy') As 'RevDate'

FROM 
   tbl2
  INNER JOIN  tbl1
    ON  tbl2.AppID =  tbl1.AppID
    Group by  tbl1.AName, tbl1.AStore, tbl1.AVr, FORMAT ( tbl2.RevDateTime,'MMM-yyyy')
    Order by FORMAT ( tbl2.RevDateTime,'MMM-yyyy') asc
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after getting this working ish, I was still having issues that if it was run over more than 12 months the months would line up so Jan15 and Jan16 next to each other (at least outside of SSMS).
Then a colleague found this:
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/09/10/group-by-month-sql.aspx
Which lead me to the following result:

```
 SELECT
   tbl1.AName
  , tbl1.AStore
  , tbl1.AVr
  ,Count ( tbl2.RevTag1) as Tag1
  ,Count ( tbl2.RevTag2) as Tag2
  ,Count ( tbl2.RevTag3) as Tag3
  ,dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, Tbl2.RevDateTime),0) as Revdate

FROM 
   tbl2
  INNER JOIN  tbl1
    ON  tbl2.AppID =  tbl1.AppID
    Group by  tbl1.AName, tbl1.AStore, tbl1.AVr, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, Tbl2.RevDateTime),0) 
    Order by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, Tbl2.RevDateTime),0) asc
```

This worked great, both in SSMS and in tables outside of SSMS (SSRS, Excel etc), due to retaining the date format 
so this is now the best solution to my particular problem.

Thanks for all you answers and thanks to Jeffs blog

Answer (score 0):

Try return also the month or year month.

```
SELECT MONTH(create_date) as name, FORMAT ( create_date,'MMM-yyyy') As 'RevDate'
```

FROM table 
order by 1

or

```
SELECT FORMAT(CREATE_DATE, 'yyyyMM') as name, FORMAT ( create_date,'MMM-yyyy') As 'RevDate'
FROM table 
order by 1
```

obs: You have a group by, so put a new column in group by with the same format in select clause.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer again..:) still i just wanted get your result with out adding additional columns in the group by clause.

I have tried with the below query and its works for me.. You can consider it if needed. :)

```
SELECT
   tbl1.AName
  , tbl1.AStore
  , tbl1.AVr
  ,Count ( tbl2.RevTag1) as Tag1
  ,Count ( tbl2.RevTag2) as Tag2
  ,Count ( tbl2.RevTag3) as Tag3
  ,FORMAT ( tbl2.RevDateTime,'MMM-yyyy') As 'RevDate'
FROM 
   tbl2
  INNER JOIN  tbl1
    ON  tbl2.AppID =  tbl1.AppID
    Group by  tbl1.AName, tbl1.AStore, tbl1.AVr, FORMAT ( tbl2.RevDateTime,'MMM-yyyy')
    order by  MONTH('1-'+FORMAT ( tbl2.RevDateTime,'MMM-yyyy')) asc , YEAR('1-'+FORMAT ( tbl2.RevDateTime,'MMM-yyyy')) asc
```

Answer (score -1):

To aggregate by month, just use `datediff(month,0,<date>)`.

you can even convert it back to date using `dateadd(month,<value>,0)`.

```
 SELECT tbl1.AName
       ,tbl1.AStore
       ,tbl1.AVr
       ,Count ( tbl2.RevTag1) as Tag1
       ,Count ( tbl2.RevTag2) as Tag2
       ,Count ( tbl2.RevTag3) as Tag3
       ,FORMAT ( dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,tbl2.RevDateTime),0),'MMM-yyyy') As 'RevDate'    
 FROM tbl2
    INNER JOIN  tbl1 ON  tbl2.AppID =  tbl1.AppID
 Group by  tbl1.AName, tbl1.AStore, tbl1.AVr, datediff(month,0,tbl2.RevDateTime)
 Order by datediff(month,0,tbl2.RevDateTime) asc
```